# Somar objeto json com js puro

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte objeto

```
json1:{A:1, B:2}
json2:{A:4, C:3}
```

Como faço para que o `json1` receba os dados do `json2`, substituindo se ele encontrar uma chave igual e movendo se ele nao encontrar, mais ou menos isso que o `json1` teria como resultado:

```
json1:{A:4, B:2, C:3}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se pretende substituir os valores todos de `json2` em `json1` então precisa apenas de percorrer as suas chaves com [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) e aplicar o valor em cada chave. Desta forma as que existem serão substituidas e as que não existem adicionadas

Exemplo:

```js
let obj1 = {A:1, B:2};
let obj2 = {A:4, C:3};

for (let chave of Object.keys(obj2)){
  obj1[chave] = obj2[chave];
}

console.log(obj1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Você também pode utilizar `Object.assign` para "mesclar" dois objetos, por exemplo:

```js
let obj1 = {A:1, B:2};
let obj2 = {A:4, C:3};

obj1 = Object.assign(obj1, obj2)

console.log(obj1);
```